# UIModalPresentationStyle View with Custom View Size

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ipad

Is it possible to have custom size of the view, when you select "**UIModalPresentationFormSheet**" Right now it seems as if this is out of our control?

According to following link, it seems you can't change the default sizes.

http://www.thizzer.com/2011/05/uimodalpresentationstyle-frame-size-ipad/

Answer (score 3):

```
MyModalViewController *targetController = [[[MyModalViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 

targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

targetController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; //transition shouldn't matter 

[self presentModalViewController:targetController animated:YES];


targetController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);//it's important to do this after 


targetController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

Comment: What if I already have set the frame size of view via interface builder?

Comment: by default UIModalPresentationStyle will use the default frame.after presenting we can change it to as our needs